# Matlab parfor slice correctly

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, slice, parfor

I have two nested loops which I want to parallelize.

```
n=100;
x=rand(1,n);
m=5;
xx=rand(1,m);

r = zeros(1,m);
for i=1:n
    q = ones(1,m);
    for j=1:n
        q = q .* (xx-x(j))/(x(i)-x(j));
    end
    r = r + q;
end
```

In order to prepare this function for palatalization, I changed local variables to global ones.

```
n=100;
x=rand(1,n);
m=5;
xx=rand(1,m);

r = ones(n,m);
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        r(i,:) = r(i,:) .* (xx-x(j))/x(i)-x(j))
    end
end
r = sum(r,1);
```

Instead of transforming a whole vector at once, let's try it with only one scalar. Also use the simplest element of x which depends on i and j. I also removed the `sum` in the end. We can add it back later.

```
n=100;
x=rand(1,n);

r = ones(n,1);
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        y = x(i)+x(j);
        r(i) = r(i) * y;
    end
end
```

**The code above is the example function, I want to parallelize.**

The inner loop always needs to access the same vector `r(i)` for one iteration of the outer loop `i`. This access is a **write** operation (`*=`), but the **order** doesn't matter for this operation.

Since nested `parfor` loops are not allowed in Matlab, I tried to pack everything in one `parfor` loop.

```
n=100;
x=rand(1,n);

r = ones(n,1);
parfor k=1:(n*n)
    %i = floor((k-1)/n)+1; % outer loop
    %j = mod(k-1,n)+1;     % inner loop
    [j,i] = ind2sub([n,n],k);
    y = x(i)+x(j);
    r(i) = r(i) * y;       % ERROR here
end
```

Since indies are calculated, Matlab still doesn't know hot to slice it.
So, I decided to move the multiplication operation outside and use linear indices.

```
n=100;
x=rand(1,n);

r = ones(n,n);
parfor k=1:(n*n)
    [j,i] = ind2sub([n,n],k);
    y = x(i)+x(j);
    r(k) = y;
end
r = prod(r,1);
r = squeeze(r); % remove singleton dimensions
```

While this does work for scalar values in the inner loop, it doesn't work for vectors in the inner loop since indices must be again calculated.

```
n=100;
x=rand(1,n);
m=5;

r = ones(n,n,m);
parfor k=1:(n*n)
    [j,i] = ind2sub([n,n],k);
    y = x(i)+x(j);
    r((k-1)*m+1:k*m) = y.*(1:m); % ERROR here
end
r = prod(r,1);
r = squeeze(r); % remove singleton dimensions
```

Although it does work, when I reshape the array.

```
n=100;
x=rand(1,n);
m=5;

r = ones(n*n,m);
parfor k=1:(n*n)
    [j,i] = ind2sub([n,n],k);
    y = x(i)+x(j);
    r(k,:) = y.*(1:m); % ERROR here
end
r = reshape(r,n,n,m);
r = prod(r,2);
r = squeeze(r); % remove singleton dimensions
```

This way, I can transform a vector `xx` to another vector `r`.

```
n=100;
x=rand(1,n);
m=5;
xx=rand(1,m);

r = ones(n*n,m);
parfor k=1:(n*n)
    [j,i] = ind2sub([n,n],k);
    y = x(i)+x(j);
    r(k,:) = y.*xx; % ERROR here
end
r = reshape(r,n,n,m);
r = prod(r,2);
r = sum(r,1);
r = reshape(r,size(xx)); % reshape output vector to input vector
```

For my parallel solution, I need an `n*n*m` array instead of a `n*m` array which seems quite inefficient.
Is there a better way of doing what I want? 
What are the advantages of other ways (prettier code, less CPU, less RAM, ...)?

**UPDATE**

In the order of trying to simplify the task and reduce it to the minimum working example of the problem, I omitted the check of `i~=j` to make it easier, although resulting in an all `NaN` result. Further, the nature of the code results in an all `1` result when adding this check. In order for the code to make sense, the factors are just weights for another vector `z`.

The more elaborate problem looks as follows:

```
n=100;
x=rand(1,n);
z=rand(1,n);
m=5;
xx=rand(1,m);

r = zeros(1,m);
for i=1:n
    q = ones(1,m);
    for j=1:n
        if i~=j
            q = q .* (xx-x(j))/(x(i)-x(j));
        end
    end
    r = r + z(i) .* q;
end
```

Comment: This may be possible to vectorize completely for each element `m` (or rather you need one for loop for each element `m` but no more). However the example code you have is faulty since it will always divide by (x(k) - x(k)) and generate NaN so it is hard to check. However I suggest that you turn around the approach and try to focus on looping over the shortest vector. This advice is not possible if you are short on memory though.

Comment: Regarding the note "nested for loop not permitted in Matlab". I would not believe it necessary. In case the outer loop runs for thousand of times you will still get a lot of tasks. It takes some time to set up a worker, so probably this is not even more effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem does not need any parallel for loop to execute. One problem is that `x(i)-x(j)` is redundandly calculated a lot of times. This is inefficient. The approach suggested calculates every number exactly once and it vectorize the operations for each element in `xx`. Since `xx` is the shortest vector by far it is almost completely vectorized. In case you want to vectorize the last loop as well this will probably just be like a hidden for loop as well, it will much more memory and the code would be more complicated (like 3D matrices and so). I took the freedom to switch minus to plus in the denominator just for testing. Minus would generate NaN for all numbers. The last approach is slightly faster. About 10 times for n=10000. I suggest you try a bit more elaborate benchmark.

```
function test()
% Initiate variables
n=100;
x=rand(1,n);
m=5;
xx=rand(1,m);

tic;
% Alternative 1
r = zeros(1,m);
for i=1:n
    q = ones(1,m);
    for j=1:n
        q = q .* (xx-x(j))/(x(i)+x(j));
    end
    r = r + q;
end
toc;

tic;
% Alternative 2
xden = bsxfun(@plus, x, x.'); % Calculate denominator
xnom = repmat(x,n,1); % Calculate nominator
xfull = (xnom./xden).'; % calculate right term on rhs.

for (k = 1:m)
    tmp= prod(xx(k)./xden - xfull); % Split in 2 calculations
    r2(k) = sum(tmp); % "r = r + xx(k)"
end
toc;

disp(r);
disp(r2);
```

Just a note in the end. Alternative 2 is faster but it is also memory expensive, so in case of memory issues a loop is to prefer. Further, there is no need for global variables in case of parallelization. In case you need this you probably have to look over your design (but in case the code is short there is not some critical, so then you should not need to bother so much).

Comment: Thanks for your approach!

I think it is a good idea to start optimizing at the actual function `(xx-x(j))/(x(i)+x(j))` instead of the loops and therefor avoid double calculations. I will have a look on that!

Note: Use `x.'` instead of `x'` and `(xnom./xden).'` instead of `(xnom./xden)'` to work correctly with complex numbers.

Comment: @darkdragon Right, I edited this. I was not aware you used complex numbers.